# New access to site analytics privilege, description missing on privileges page

Tags: bug, status-completed, site-analytics

Stack Overflow implemented a new milestone privilege called [access to site anaytics](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) . But I failed to see a small description on the privilege page for that particular privilege.

[image]

Comment: Ha! Didn't know about this. Cool.

Comment: I can't see link to access site analytics..

Comment: Wohoo yet another feature I can get :D

Comment: @Mr.Alien really? I added the link in my post.